# Unity3D: Instantiate creates NullReferenceException

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation

```
Transform child = GameObject.FindWithTag("state").transform;
    child.name = first_guy+""; child.tag = first_guy+"";
    GameObject  child_dup = Instantiate( child, new Vector3(0,0,0),Quaternion.identity) as GameObject; 
    Debug.Log (child_dup.name);
```

The above code gives me error, "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object". 
Is this because I am trying to instantiate a local variable? How to duplicate a gameobject in run time?

Comment: If you are trying to post code, you need 4 spaces before each line of code.

Comment: I was fighting for that :D It was giving error..

Comment: Is first_guy some string variable you have set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to instantiate a `Transform` which is a component and cannot be instantiated, as it must be attached to a GameObject.

```
Instantiate( child.gameObject, ...)
```

Comment: This. You're probably wanting to get the actual GameObject and duplicate it, duplicating the transform isn't making a new instance of the object. Side note, but instantiation wreaks havoc on your garbage collection, and for a game engine like Unity you should look at setting up an object pool if you are doing a lot of instantiations.

Comment: Not entirely right. You most definately can Instantiate() a transform. Instantiate() will take any kind of Unity Object and clone it. In case of Components (like Transform) it will not only clone the Component, but also the GameObject it is attached to. The reason why OP gets a NullReferenceException is that Instantiate() will return the clone of the object it was passed, in this case, the Transform of the newly created GameObject. As return value of type Transform is cast to GameObject, the result will be null, and the NullReferenceException will be thrown from Debug.Log(), not Instantiate().

Comment: @ThomasHilbert Yes, you are correct.  I forget sometimes that Unity does some extra stuff inside the black box that is Instantiate in order to be more  flexible.